# How to show two or more than two different product categories in Volusion home page

Tags: volusion

Can we do this in Volusion homepage?

Here is screenshot what I want to do.
[image]

Comment: please explain your problem well and specify what you have tried so far to achieve this goal.

Comment: what I want to achieve is, we want top coffee products on top and top tea products below it as in screenshot above. I can only see Homepage featured option, but it only shows random featured products from all category.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current functionality only allows you to specify "homepage featured" and as you say, the sort order is random.

Also, if you have more products flagged than are allowed on the homepage, any extras will not be displayed.

What you're trying to achieve could be done with jQuery, but it would be a hack.  Then again -- working with Volusion is all about workarounds!

Answer (score 0):

You can control which products are "featured" by going to the Product page (in the Admin Panel) under Product Display / Feature Product on the Homepage (dropdown).

Also, if you go into Config Variables / Search for "Home Page" and you can turn on other Home Page sections that feature certain products (like Super Deals, Top Sellers, New Products).  You can rename these sections for your purposes (like Top Sellers could be changed to Top Tea Products).

Again, then you'd have to set a product to be in these "categories."  That may be the easiest solution with built-in functionality.